# AlarmManager cancel() not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

This is my first post here. I have searched all around for this topic, but nothing seems to help. When the code below gets executed, the alarm still goes off, when it should not.. meaning that I cannot cancel the alarm, making my app useless for API's lower than 21. Any idea why? Please help! I should mention that when I try this code using an API22 emulator(nexus one) from Android Studio it works, but when I use it with an API18 emulator(samsung s3) from genymotion it does not.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 8, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: After further testing, using different emulators, it does the same for API 17, 16, 19. Still works on API 22.. any workaround?

Comment: Are you really calling `cancel()` immediately after calling `set()`?

Comment: Do You have any broadcast receiver?

Comment: yes I do. Daniel that is for testing purpose. The alarm works!!! and it should not given that code. That is the problem.

Comment: Try giving it some time to set the alarm before cancelling it, it may be a timing issue.

Comment: yay, adding a handler to post the cancel worked. TY!

Comment: would upvote.. but can't yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just not giving `set()` enough time to set the alarm before you're calling `cancel()`.

Put the call to `cancel()` in a separate code block so that it's not being called immediately after `set()`, and it should work.